# Sending E-Mails through Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: c#, .net, email-client

I would like to send e-mails through a Microsoft Exchange server. Is it even possible through SMTP for example? The server is "be01.ix.netplace.com" in case this will help in anything. I tried many sample codes but they all didn't work.
Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to send SMTP email through Exchange - my linux boxes do it all the time. However, you have to set Exchange up to allow SMTP connections.

Coding a SMTP emailer is simplicity itself, either connect to the server on the correct port and send the commands to it, or use a library (of which there are loads).

To test your SMTP emailing, telnet to the server on port 25 and manually type the mail commands. We used to do this at university to send emails to people from themselves, obviously most SMTP ports are secured to stop you doing this :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to send email *to* Exchange server. It's also possible to send email *through* an Exchange server as long as the forwarding option is not turned off on Exchange server.